# How to open a url in the same tab upon clicking a link in the slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to open a URL in the same tab upon clicking a link in the slack, but it is redirecting to the another tab.Can any one help me with this issue and I want to do it in using JSON code

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

Slack will always open a URL in another tab / window and does not provide an option to change that behavior.